# Implicit Differentiation problem (Exponential Derivatives) Please help!

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

Use the process of implicit differentiation to find $dy/dx$ given that:

$$x^2e^y − y^2e^x=0 $$

I am trying first to find $y$,

$$y^2e^x = x^2e^y$$

$$y^2 = (x^2e^y)/e^x$$

$$y = \sqrt{(x^2e^y)/e^x}$$

Is this correct? I have the feeling it is not.

Comment: It leaves things a bit more complex if you bring the $e^y$ over to the right and take the square root. I would try leaving it at $y^2e^x = x^2e^y$ and differentiating both sides with respect to x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math is right, but if you are using implicit differentiation the point is *not* to solve for $y$. Instead you would differentiate each term with respect to $x$, assuming that $y$ is some function of $x$ whose derivative is $dy/dx$. For instance, the term $y^2e^x$ yields

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}e^x+y^2e^x$$

Hopefully this helps as a starting point. (You will need to differentiate the equation term by term as shown, then solve for $dy/dx$.)

Comment: So, maybe I can just differentiate the equation y^2e^x=x^2e^y?

Comment: For the left, the derivative = e^xy^2+(2e^x)(y) and for the right the derivative is 2xe^y+e^yx^2? Is this correct?

Comment: Well, you've got to remember that $y$ is a function of $x$, so whenever you take the derivative of $y^2$ or $e^y$ you have to multiply by $dy/dx$ (chain rule).

Answer (score -2):

So, implicitly differentiating;
$$x^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}e^{y}+2x e^{y}-\left(y^{2}e^{x}-2y\frac{dy}{dx}e^{x}\right)=0$$
Collecting like terms
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(x^{2}e^{y}-2ye^{x} \right)=y^{2}e^{x}-2xe^{y}$$
From which it is readily seen that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{2}e^{x}-2xe^{y}}{\left(x^{2}e^{y}-2ye^{x} \right)}$$